# Reverse out title header so background is red and font is white

Tags: header-footer

Is it possible to reverse out a title header, so the background is red and the font is white?

```
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{\LARGE{\textcolor{red}{TITLE HEADER}}}}
```

Comment: Your are not providing much information ;-)

Comment: Do you want the red background to extend to the full `\textwidth` (from left to right margin) or just to enclose the "Title header" string?

Comment: I would like the background to extend from the left to right margin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very primitive way with `\colorbox{red}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{...}}}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2\fboxsep}  % minimal increase
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[C]{\colorbox{red}{\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\leftmark}}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{One}
\clearpage
\section{Two}
\section{Three}
\section{Four}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

A version with full spanning from left to the right. I don't recommend this, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{calc}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2\fboxsep}

\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{\colorbox{red}{\parbox[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}{\centering\textbf{\textcolor{white}{\leftmark}}}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section{One}
\clearpage
\section{Two}
\clearpage
\section{Three}
\clearpage
\section{Four}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to `\protect` the `\colorbox`. You'll also need to increase the `\headheight` value.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, you're right. I thought, `\colorbox` is fragile, but I confused it with `\color@box`. And I've increased the `\headheight` (I ignored it for simplicity)

Comment: How can I increase the red background so it goes from the left margin to the right?

Comment: @adam.888: Your original question did not say anything about spanning the full textwidth. This would also that you could not use the left and right header fields any longer.

Comment: @adam.888: See my update, please